# C - Determining all if all even bits are set to 1

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, puzzle

Determine if all even place bits (counting from left to right) are set to 1. For instance, `0101 0101` would count whereas `1011 1000` would not count.

If the the bit has 1's in all even places, return 1, or else return 0.

Constraints: must only use bitwise operators. Cannot use conditionals. Biggest integer you can use in an expression is `0xFF`.

Here is my code:

```
int allEvenBits(int X) {
    int x1 = !((X & 0x55) ^ 0x55);
    int x2 = !(((X >> 8) & 0x55) ^ 0x55);
    int x3 = !(((X >> 16) & 0x55) ^ 0x55);
    int x4 = !(((X >> 24) & 0x55) ^ 0x55);
    return x1 + x2 + x3 + x4;
```

}

The above returns 1 for the following: `1011 0010 1001 0010 1011 1001 1111 1111`

How can I modify this to make it work with the constraint?

Comment: What about `1111 1111`? i.e., do odd bits matter?

Comment: @dawg odd bits do not matter, so that would count.

Comment: @barakmanos I can't use integers greater than 0xFF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `>>` counts as a bitwise operator, the following only needs constants up to 16.

```
int allEven(unsigned x) {
  x &= x >> 16;
  x &= x >> 8;
  x &= x >> 4;
  x &= x >> 2;
  return x&1;
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution and works perfectly. I am a beginner in C. If you wouldn't mind, can you explain how this logic works? Specifically, I don't understand what the operators &= do.

Comment: `x &= x >> 16` is shorthand (valid C) for `x = x & (x >> 16)` . The same way `x += 5` is the same as `x = x + 5`

Comment: I still don't get how it works, especially why only needs to count 16?

Comment: @SittingBull: It's not really counting; it's more like a binary expansion. Each of the statements in turn effectively tears the integer in half and combines the two halves with a bitwise and. So if you start with 32 bits (the assumption), then the first half is 16 bits from the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use bit-shifting and bitwise-and:

```
int f(unsigned x) {
  x&= x>>16;
  x&= x>>8;
  x&= x>>4;
  x&= x>>2;
  return x&1;
}
```

If we had bigger constants, this would be best:

```
int f(unsigned x) {const unsigned mask = 0x55555555; return mask == (mask&x);}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question specifies that the biggest constant you're allowed to use is `0xFF`

Comment: @user3386109: Saw that restriction too late, though changed then.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those silly puzzle questions that requires a sub-optimal solution, for no particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`:

```
int all_even(int x) {
    int all_even = (0x55<<24)|(0x55<<16)|(0x55<<8)|0x55;
    return x == ((x & ~all_even) | all_even);
}
```

Read as "If I set all the even bits in `x`, is that new number the same as `x`?"

Comment: I'm not sure `==` would be allowed.